# Post deleted having an answer that could be useful

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions

Few days ago I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65163260/2571705) question. But the question has now been deleted, but I think my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65169483/2571705), which is the only answer, could be useful to somebody else in future (at least in my perspective). Is there a way to restore it, or make it visible to a wider audience?

Comment: Undeleted now. In the future, note that things like this don't need a Meta question. You can simply raise a moderator flag. Use the custom reason to provide us with a link and your rationale for undeletion. Also note that, had the question been upvoted *and* answered, the asker would not have been able to delete it. ;-)

Comment: NO! but you can see it Activity > Reputation/All Actions

Comment: @CodyGray are you sure rule blocking deletion is "the *question* been upvoted and answered"? I thought "the question has *upvoted answer*"... OP would definitely have much less initiative to delete question if it is upvoted, but...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oh, oops; you're right. I was thinking of Roomba. Criteria for self-deletion are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Comment: I often say silly things, but the original state of the question looked pretty alright to me too... I don't really see why it needed downvoting. Just a run of the mill how to question with effort shown.

Comment: Yes, the question doesn't deserve any downvotes.

Comment: @CodyGray *You can simply raise a moderator flag.* Does that apply to all users, or users with under 10K rep?

Comment: In the case of questions deleted by the asker just after having received an answer, you can raise a moderator flag and request undeletion. That applies to all users, @AnnZen. But it *doesn't* apply to when the *community* deletes the post through the normal process.