# Why was this moderator flag to undelete this post declined?

Tags: support, specific-question, declined-flags, deleted-questions

This question *(10K+ rep)* was deleted by its OP 5 days ago without any explanation *(there were no comments by the OP or any other user)*: [Having trouble making the Sierpinski Carpet using recursion only and python turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65118534/13552470).

I answered the question just one hour before it got deleted.

The question was basically how to create a turtle program that draws the [Sierpinski Carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_carpet) using recursion, and without using any loops. It's a unique question, they showed what they have tried, it had a positive score, and it has my answer that I spent a long time on *(not much competition in the [turtle-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turtle-graphics) tag :p)*.

Disappointed by the deletion, I asked the OP why they deleted it, but they never replied, so I shrugged it off and moved on.

Now, today this post got posted on meta: [Post deleted having an answer that could be useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403471/13552470) which informed me that I can raise a moderator flag on such cases, so... ***I did***.

But it got declined. Can someone help me understand why?

**EDIT**

Contents of my flag:

> This is the only question that asks to create the Sierpinski Carpet with python without using any loops.

I should have instead flagged as:

> This question (deleted by its OP one day after I answered) is the only question that asks to create the Sierpinski Carpet with python without using any loops. Please undelete.

*Credits: Rob♦*

Comment: Nothing in your flag indicated that you were requesting undeletion

Comment: Without seeing the contents of your flag, it's hard to say why it got declined. fwiw, I've never had a flag declined when I've asked for undeletion of an answered post that's deleted by the OP.

Comment: You'd have to explain what useful stuff the answer contained. Did the question get closed, perhaps? One could make an argument that the answer may not have been useful.

Comment: Side note: don't provide copy-paste ready answers for homework questions *if you are the first one to answer*. Normally author will wait for code that can be turned in before deleting the post - so if you are providing the second answer you are safe from removal as question with multiple answer can't be deleted by author... For the first one stick to just explaining problems with OP's code (if they provided any of they own).

Comment: @Rob Ohhhhhhh... it make perfect sense now!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Okay, fixed it. I tried fixing their code before, but it was out of my understanding.

Comment: @10Rep I don't think it got closed... I think my answer's helpful :)

Comment: @cigien Relatable. Neither have I! *(except this incident)*

Comment: Thanks for adding the flag contents. Yes, you need to be explicit. In fact, IIUC, you don't even need to mention the merits of either the question or the answer. My flags simply say something like "Post was deleted by OP after receiving answer". I don't recall how many of the posts actually got undeleted though.

Comment: @cigien You *do* need to make an argument regarding the merits... That's the only basis on which we would undelete. We aren't going to undelete crap. You may have gotten away with omitting the discussion of the merits if the Q&A was self-evidently good, but you should not rely on that.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, I see. If I care about the undeletion, I'll make sure to be explicit about why. Frankly, I only do it because OPs shouldn't be deleting posts after receiving answers. I don't really pay attention to the quality of the post when I flag those posts.

Comment: @cigien Nothing wrong with deleting stuff that needs to be deleted anyway :-)

Comment: @CodyGray I guess not. I've been imagining that mods have a talking to with the OP to ensure they don't do that in the future, when a post might not be worth deleting. If there's no point to it, I'll stop raising those flags.

Comment: It got undeleted, so now there is a better chance of prof's anti-cheat scripts detecting it.

Comment: @MartinJames Don't look at *my* answer. Another user would've answered anyway it if I hadn't :)

Answer (score 12):

To expand a bit on this comment from a moderator:

> Nothing in your flag indicated that you were requesting undeletion
> – [Rob ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403486/why-was-this-moderator-flag-to-undelete-this-post-declined#comment813061_403486)

Assume, when writing flag text, that moderators are completely incapable of making any inferences about what needs to be done and why.  This isn't an insult to the moderators: they just have a **lot** of flags to handle and not much time to handle each one.  They've never seen the post before, they have no context for its content, and they get a lot of weird flags that were sent for the wrong reason that they need to correctly decline.

If you have a post you want undeleted, include something like "Please undelete."  If you're flagging spam that's not obvious enough for a Spam flag, start it with "Spam: ", and so on.  As a rule of thumb, the problem that the moderator needs to solve should be obvious within a few seconds of reading the flag.  If it's not, add more explanation.

Comment: It's not even limited time. It's limited context. In particular, we are limited in our ability to access the context that is in your head.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but independently of the clarity of the flag, I really don't see why we need to mod-flag to undelete at all. 10k+ users already have undelete vote rights, so this is really something that the community can do itself; we really don't need a diamond to do it for us. Just vote to undelete.

The one problem I see with this is that the current moderation tools don't have a way to indicate the reason for the undelete vote. I'm not sure what a good solution to that would be, though.

Comment: *Correct me if I'm wrong* Alright: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403471/post-deleted-having-an-answer-that-could-be-useful?noredirect=1#comment813058_403471

Comment: @AnnZen I disagree with Cody in that case - I really don't see any particular reason that we need to mod-flag to undelete, given that that's something that the community can do itself.

Comment: @AnnZen While that moderator is a smart person, I disagree with them: you have 10k rep, you can vote to undelete.

Comment: Yes, of course you *can* vote to undelete. But it takes 3 votes to get the post undeleted, so your vote is not sufficient. A moderator can immediately restore the post. A user who decides to "take their toys and go home" (i.e., delete the question immediately after receiving an answer) is breaking the rules, so this is a mod-flaggable issue.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica how those 10K + users will be aware of that item in need of undeleting? Unless it is tight circle of friends who exchange all urls to act on you will not know that deleted question need to be undeleted (as you will not see it at all).